# Cannot access Asterisk sip from remote location

Tags: centos, iptables, firewall, asterisk, sip

I've used [this tutorial](http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+firewall+rules) to configure my iptables so I can access asterisk sip from outside of my server.

My `iptables -L` looks like this

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source     destination
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere   anywhere      state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere   anywhere
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere   anywhere
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere   anywhere      state NEW tcp dpt:ssh
REJECT     all  --  anywhere   anywhere      reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere   anywhere      udp dpt:sip
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere   anywhere      udp dpt:iax
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere   anywhere      udp dpt:5036
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere   anywhere      udp dpts:ndmp:dnp
ACCEPT     udp  --  anywhere   anywhere      udp dpt:mgcp-callagent

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source     destination
REJECT     all  --  anywhere   anywhere      reject-with icmp-host-prohibited

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source     destination
```

Now, when the iptables are turned off then I can register on sip client without any problems, but when it's turned on then firewall blocks it. Whats wrong with this iptables config, what should I do to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a reject all rule in the chain:

`REJECT     all  --  anywhere   anywhere      reject-with icmp-host-prohibited`

Move that to the end and you'll be all set.

Comment: Now that I think of it, why do you have a `ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere   anywhere` rule too?

Comment: The display is incomplete because he didn't use `-v`.

Comment: @NathanC: This rules was on the machine when I got there. How can I move single rule? Where can I edit this?